# I have an issue with particles not showing up when facing the z-axis in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I have an issue with particles not showing up when facing the z-axis in Unity.

[Youtube record](https://www.youtube.com/live/Iv5Lj-nZVPg?feature=share)

I tried to rotate it and change the shape option but still the particle is invisible on the  z axis.

I saw other posts about unity particle, and most of them the problem is camera position. So I changed it's position - but it is not a solution.

Comment: What's the transform position of your main camera?

Comment: it's 50 in z axis, and I think the camera doesn't matter. Because I solved it!

I guess the problem is the Sorting Layer in Sprite Renderer. I chainged the particles's Sorting Layer to change it's layer in front of Background Layer and now I can see them!

Answer (score 0):

The author of this question. I solved it myself!
Most of the other articles on Stackoverflow said it was the camera, but in my case it wasn't the camera.
The problem was the Sorting Layer in the Sprite Renderer.

there's so many layers...[image: 1]

The Background was in the Background Layer, but the particles were in the Default Layer, which meant they were hidden by the Background.[image: 2]

I changed the Layer in the particle's Renderer settings and it was visible.[image: 3]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).